# How to get the Skype call duration?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, skype, skype4com, skype-uri.js

I am working on small call center application using PHP and MySQL. To be precise, I am doing it through the CodeIgniter framework. I am adding a link to the web page. When the user clicks on this link, it will call the number automatically through Skype if Skype is installed.

But when the user ends this call, how can I get the call duration or the call ending time? I want to save this data into my database.

I have tried to get some information about this problem, but I did not get any nice solution for it.

Comment: As far as i know... U cannot really achieve it...

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any Skype information because it hasn't any API. Your code wrong even now: when I click on `skype:` link I can cancel call before first connection-attempt, so maximum what You can achieve is click count to Skype link.